# Codename One & SQLite consecutive tests & receiving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V exception

Tags: java, sqlite, codenameone

I am trying to run consecutive tests with codename one.

The first test opens the simulator and accesses a sqlite database and returns true and closes that simulator. The next test opens another simulator and runs that test, but this one doesn't access the db so I'm assuming why that test also returns true.

The third test however does access the db, and this is where the exception happens.

```
 [java] [EDT] 0:0:0,949 - Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
 [java] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Users\cocoa\AppData\Local\Temp\sqlite-3.7.151-amd64-sqlitejdbc.dll already loaded in another classloader
 [java] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

I've searched around and I'm assuming it's happening because the .dll is not being unloaded and the tests are trying to load it again. Is there a way to unload the .dll, or a workaround so that consecutive tests work?

I'm using sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar (latest version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue mentioned here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2175

Unfortunately our attempts at fixing it have failed. This is the exact cause. The SQLite plugin doesn't play nicely with classloaders.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
Is there a workaround? A way to close a simulator completely before the next test loads? I never have a problem when running and re-running the simulator, it's only when the tests go for it.

Comment: No. We might be able to enhance test runner to support spawning new JVM instances, that might patch that. Unfortunately we're understaffed. If you want to implemented this as an option (with a flag to enable) you could probably change https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/TestRunner.java and submit a pull request

Comment: I may look into that. Thank you Shai